# Android C# TextView.setGravity

Tags: c#, android, textview, xamarin

first question here.

I am trying to develop an app using Xamarin and targetting android with C#. My problem starts when i instantize an instance of a TextView and try to manipulate it via code:

```
text = new TextView(context);
text.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(hwidth, hheight);
text.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
```

now i have been reading the android API and i need to change the gravity of this Textview so that the text is in the center but when i try:

```
text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

It simply errors saying that Android.Widget.TextView does not contain a definition for 'setGravity'. Am i missing something ridiculously simple or what?

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @jarvis mentioned in the Comment

```
TextView.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
```

This will work.

Comment: @jarvis : Your code is Correct as you write 
`text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`  But its For Native Android . 
So now you want to implement that in C# (Xamarin) so there are some changes in syntax 
So the code is `TextVeiw.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;` By this way you can solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set LAYOUT gravity instead of gravity, you can try :

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);
```

xamarin allows you to use XML files ?
If yes, you can set gravity into:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/smiley"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     />
```

Hope this help

Comment: Okay, try this and i get an error saying that Android.Views.Gravity does not contain a definition for 'Center'.

text.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(hwidth, hheight, Gravity.Center);

Comment: The better way is to do with xml, place your TextView in a Linear or RelativeLayout, and then apply android:layout_gravity="center" to your LAYOUT...

Comment: Yes i know that is possible but i want to manipulate the layout dynamicly, not through a xml file.

Comment: AAA i found it finally, if anyone is interested it is 
text.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center

i wonder why i can't seem to find any documentation on the text.Gravity attribute or the GravityFlags.Center value. All documentatin tells me to use the setGravity methods but they don't seem to work in xamarin C#...