# Why isn't Gravity taking effect on my buttons?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using [Signature Pad](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad) and I would like to move the buttons that I add on top of that view using `Gravity` but nothing happens, I have tried several flags and they all look the same. I also tried to add the `signature` view to the `layout` at the end of the method but that didn't change anything either.

The activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "Authorize Buyin", ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
    public class Sign : Activity
    {
        LinearLayout layout;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.sign_dialog);

            layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutSign);

            CreateSignaturePad();
        }

        private void CreateSignaturePad()
        {
            var signature = new SignaturePadView(this)
            {
                StrokeWidth = 3f,
                BackgroundColor = Android.Graphics.Color.White,
                StrokeColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Black,
            };

            layout.AddView(signature,
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent));

            /* Add Clear Button */
            Button btnClear = new Button(this) { Text = "Borrar" };
            signature.AddView(btnClear);



            /* Add Authorize Button */
            Button btnAuthorize = new Button(this) { Text = "Authorize" };
            btnAuthorize.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            signature.AddView(btnAuthorize);                    
        }
    }
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSign"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="2dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `setGravity(...)`?

Comment: I might need to delete the "Android" tag. I'm using Xamarin and setGravity doesn't exist but instead they use the Gravity property as far as I know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026596/android-c-sharp-textview-setgravity

Comment: Ah, okay. Out of my range of exp.

Comment: I guess `Gravity` on `Button` is change the text position (start, center, end), So if you want to center the `Button` inside `LinearLayout`, try to set  `Gravity` on your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Makes sense. I need to maybe use a RelativeLayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

`SignatureView` is inherited from RelativeLayout. `signature` is `SignatureView`.

This is how I finally solved it:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);

            Button btnAuthorize = new Button(this) { Text = "Authorize" };
            btnAuthorize.LayoutParameters = lp;
            btnAuthorize.Click += BtnAuthorize_Click;
            signature.AddView(btnAuthorize);
```